# Unmanaged DLL to Managed C# win32 application. Entry with Class

Tags: c#, c++, dll

My problem is trying to access a defined `dll` function inside a class called function.

```
namespace MathLibrary
{
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec(dllexport) double Functions::Add(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) double Functions::Multiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a * b;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) double Functions::AddMultiply(double a, double b)
    {
        return a + (a * b);
    }
}

}
```

This is what I have From C++ and created MathLibrary.dll
Now I would like to use it in C# so I tried PInvoke method. I am not sure what procedure is this called, please inform me I am wrong.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("MathLibrary.dll", CallingConvention =        CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern double Add(double a, double b);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double myNumber = Add(10, 5); <- this is the Line. I suspect that it is because the Add is inside a class name Functions that I why I can't Access it and having error that there is no Entry point for the method Add.

        Console.WriteLine(myNumber);
    }
}
```

The MathLibrary.h looks like this and I don't even know if it is still necessary to add __declspec(dllexport) on the MathLibrary.cpp, example above. Since I already have #ifdef for the dllexport in here.

```
#pragma once

#ifdef MATHLIBRARY_EXPORTS  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
#define MATHLIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

namespace MathLibrary
{
// This class is exported from the MathLibrary.dll  
class Functions
{
public:
    // Returns a + b  
    static MATHLIBRARY_API double Add(double a, double b);

    // Returns a * b  
    static MATHLIBRARY_API double Multiply(double a, double b);

    // Returns a + (a * b)  
    static MATHLIBRARY_API double AddMultiply(double a, double b);
};
}
```

So going back to the Question. I suspect that I have to Define the DLL function from the PInvoke or DLLImport that the Method is inside the `Function` CLass, which I am not aware how to do.

Error is. Cannot find Entry Point `Add`.

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close to making it work, and your suspicion is correct.  In order for your .NET code to PInvoke into a DLL, it needs to find the expected C-style function symbol in your DLL.  Since your DLL is being built with C++ code (regardless of the extern "C" you have), the function name is being mangled and so .NET cannot find what it is expecting.

#### Solution

To fix this, your function *declarations* need to be pure C (and do keep the extern "C" around those declarations).  This means no namespaces, no classes, no references, etc.  However, the function *implementation* code can be C++ if you want.  You just need .NET and your DLL to agree on the declarations (interfaces).

#### Suggestion

If for some reason you need to keep all that C++ code the way it is (because other code is using it), then just create a new thin C layer on top of it which will be your DLL public interface used by .NET.